# Scaling shapes formula

Tags: geometry

Good evening!
I want to learn geometry and I have imagine a problem for me!
I have on a square pane placed in random positions some figures as squares ovals and more complicated figures.
I want to scale them all with center the center of pane.
Is there any formulas or something that can help me to manage to solve the problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "scale them all with center the center of pane"? What background do you have? What have you tried or thought of so far?

Comment: Imagine that you take video this pane and zooming in to the center of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy if the center of the square is at the origin $(0,0)$.  In order to scale by a factor of $s$, you just replace every point $(x,y)$ by $(sx, sy)$.  So the thing to do is to translate the center of the square to the origin, where the problem is easy to solve, solve it, and then translate the center back to its original position.  Let the center of the square be $(a,b).$ Then replace $(x,y)$ by $$(s(x-a)+a, s(y-b)+b)$$